# The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-tomcat-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found

Tags: apache, maven-2, tomcat

I keep getting this error when I call 'tomcat:run'.

*The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-tomcat-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found*

My company hosts mvn repositories locally via 'activeprofile'.  Is this preventing mvn from acquiring the plugin from the WWW location?  If so, how can I activate that too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared up after I deleted the repository in ~\.m2 (%userprofile%\.m2). Maybe poor interaction b/t various maven/tomcat eclipse plugin

Comment: This happens sometimes (corrupted metadata). I should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

The company repos (assuming they are using a repo manager) controlles what is in it ...so this has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

> My company hosts mvn repositories locally via 'activeprofile'. Is this preventing mvn from acquiring the plugin from the WWW location?

It's impossible to answer this question, it all depends of the configuration of your maven client and/or the corporate repository.

> If so, how can I activate that too...

Assuming your company does not allow accessing the central repository, bypassing this policy is not a good idea. You should discuss your requirement with the people administering the repository.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case it looks like a problem in my repository.